# Webkit: Access DOMWindow object returned from window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, base64

I'm having several **base64** encoded images. Those images have a **click event handler** which open a new **window / tab** and append the image into that newly created window. This works perfectly in **Firefox** (testing on 3.6.x) but all **WebKit** browsers so far, deny the access to the **window object** for some reason.

---

**Example**

```
jQuery('<img>', {
    src: "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDQAOAJEAANno6wBmZgAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAANAA4AQAIjjI8Iyw3GhACSQecutsFV3nzgNi7SVEbo06lZa66LRib2UQAAOw%3D%3D",
    click: function() {
        var largeprev = window.open('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + escape('<div/>'), 'large'),
            that      = this;

        largeprev.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
            largeprev.alert('loaded');
            largeprev.document.querySelectorAll('div')[0].appendChild(that);
        }, false);
    }
}).prependTo(document.body);
```

Code in action: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bM6uY/

I messed around with this the whole day. I need to create the new window by passing in a **data-uri** with text/html content-type, to have some node in the new window in which I can append the image. This is necesarry, because if you are dealing with huge images and you would just pass the **base 64 encoding** into **window.open()**, all this data would do into the **URL bar**, which slows down things pretty heavy.

So I had the idea to open a new window with a node and apply some Javascript magic to append the image.

Works great in FF, but I can't find a solution for Chrome/Safari. Any idea appreciated.

---

**Update**

The only cross-browser working solution so far, seems to be `document.write()`:

```
jQuery('<img>', {
    src: "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDQAOAJEAANno6wBmZgAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAANAA4AQAIjjI8Iyw3GhACSQecutsFV3nzgNi7SVEbo06lZa66LRib2UQAAOw%3D%3D",
    click: function() {
        var virtualdom = '<html><body><img src="' + this.src + '"/></body></html>',
            prev       = window.open('', 'large');

        prev.document.open();
        prev.document.write(virtualdom);
        prev.document.close();
    }
}).prependTo(document.body);
```

Code in action: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bM6uY/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only cross-browser working solution so far, seems to be document.write():

```
jQuery('<img>', {
    src: "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDQAOAJEAANno6wBmZgAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAANAA4AQAIjjI8Iyw3GhACSQecutsFV3nzgNi7SVEbo06lZa66LRib2UQAAOw%3D%3D",
    click: function() {
        var virtualdom = '<html><body><img src="' + this.src + '"/></body></html>',
            prev       = window.open('', 'large');

        prev.document.open();
        prev.document.write(virtualdom);
        prev.document.close();
    }
}).prependTo(document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to open a blank html doc with an image with it's src attribute set to the data url?

```
var data = "data:image/png;base64,RASSf4wwedfAAAA....",
    html= "<html><head> <title>Image Preview</title></head>"+
                "<body><img src='"+data+"'></img></body></html>",
    largePreview = open('');
largePreveiw.document.write(html);
largePreveiw.document.close();
```

using HTMLDocument.write isn't best, but I do not think that there is a element you could add the content to...

Comment: This would be the same problem I described. All data goes into the **address bar** of the browser. I'm dealing with huges images, this hangs / slows the browser. Btw, this would probably not even work without a `data:text/html` prefix.

Comment: @jAndy oops... sorry I thought open worked differently... i think i fixed the answer.

Comment: @jAndy: I don't believe this answer works anyway, as you cannot pass arbitrary html to `window.open` AFAIK. You *can* pass `"about:blank"`, then: `largePreview.document.open(); largePreview.document.write(html); largePreview.document.close();`, which is in the same spirit as this answer.

Comment: @Roatin Marth i don't think that about:blank works in all browsers, in most documentation it says to use a blank string

Comment: @Roatin Marth: well, you pointed me on a working solution at least, see my update in the question. This works in all browsers so far.

Comment: @invisible: woops yes, empty string is better than about:blank. Point is anything other than html.